# Why is the datasheet view not working for one user?

Tags: 2010, document-library, view, datasheet

There is a document library in a SharePoint 2010 site. It has a datasheet view for mass editing, but one user is not able to get the view. He can navigate to it, but it just brings up a standard "list view" for him. Is there some plugin that he needs or something?

Comment: Please make sure that the user uses IE to acces the DataSheet View

Answer (score 1):

If the user for some reason is accessing it with a IE 64 bit you will not able to see Datasheet view (to check this is the case see if the user sees the button open with explorer as grayed out).

Datasheet view works with Firefox and Chrome however I noticed that unlike IE, those 2 browsers do not allow PASTE into the datasheet view.